# deploying a war file to a remote centos 7 server

Tags: centos, java, webserver, tomcat

If tomcat is installed in a remote `centos 7` dedicated web server, and a `war` file is placed in the `webapps` folder, how would you set things up so that `http` requests originating all over the internet for `somedomain.com` get mapped to that `war` file?

Obviously, you would login to your domain registrar and enter the `dns`, but how do you generate the `dns` in `CentOS 7`?  What else do you have to configure in `CentOS 7`? And how?

Comment: This is a really big question, you should try breaking it into chunks and taking it a piece at a time:

1) How to install a war file in tomcat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7
2) How to configure DNS to point to a web server (you should consider fronting tomcat with apache/mod_jk or nginx)
3) How to setup SSL - this can be a bear to get right.

Comment: @IanMcGowan Thank you for getting back to me.  I already know how to put the `war` in the `webapps` folder and everything works fine on `localhost:8080/someapp`.  And I know how to log into my domain registrar and enter `DNS` for a server so that requests from the internet get directed to the server.  What I am asking is 1.) how to generate the valid `DNS` in CentOS server and 2.) how to make sure that requests for the `DNS` that reach the CentOS server get mapped to the particular `war`.  This is a dedicated server, so we do not need to deal with the confusion of routing multiple `war` files.

Comment: If you can connect from the outside (let's say to 10.1.2.123:8080/someapp), then when you create a new DNS A record, say www.mydomain.com, you should be able to just go to www.mydomain.com:8080/someapp.  You don't have to configure DNS on the CentOS server.